# Generating SQL Schema from XML

Tags: java, sql, oracle, xsd

We are using an Oracle 11 database and a java development environment (using Eclipse) and would like to migrate several xml schemas to SQL schemas.

Have looked ax xsd but really need something that we can run from ant/
Eclipse without SQL Server installed.

Regards,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use JAXB to generate Java objects, and use Hibernate to create a schema based on the class hierarchy.

That being said, it depends on what you are trying to do, and I think such solutions are probably going to be brittle and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

What is the XML schema definition? Is it proprietary or open? An XSLT transform can be easily scripted to do the conversion.