# Error creating SQL FOREIGN KEY constraint in C# using Management.Smo

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I hope you are well!

I used code from a another thread/problem on stack overflow ([Generating SQL Server DB from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467176/generating-sql-server-db-from-xsd)) and it worked really nice up until one point. I honestly don't know enough about SQL and MS SQL to debug and fix this. any help will be appreciated.

As far as I understand you need to specify if it should cascade delete and cascade update, if that is the case, I want to do it, just don't know how. See 'my' code and the error in the screenshot below:

[image: Pic of code + error]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using SMO instead of sending equivalent SQL to the server?

Comment: @Dai Well I didn't write the code, I updated my post with the link where I found the code, I am just trying to write my XSD to my SQL Server database. It is quite a huge XSD other wise I would've done it manually

Comment: @Hancs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths/852047

Comment: @Vijay Thanks! So at least now I know that I should specify no action on delete/update. Now how do I do that in the code example above? Do you have any idea?